# К какому стилю можно отнести этот текст?

Tags: стилистика, стили-речи

Наталья: Дарья, добрый вечер!
Психолог: Наталья, здравствуйте! С каким  вопросом, ситуацией или проблемой вы бы хотели сегодня поработать?
Наталья: Наверно, с отсутствием смысла, цели в моей жизни.
Психолог: Цель и смысл всегда отсутствовали? Или это ощущение, бессмысленности, бесперспективности в жизни, появилось какое-то время назад?
Наталья: Да, это у меня временное явление. Я раньше как-то строила планы поступить на бюджет в престижный институт, потом строила цель работать в конкретной компании, потом стремилась добиться успехов в спорте. Потом, проработав 8 лет в одной конторе, меня уволили. Я родила ребенка. И теперь я не понимаю, что дальше?
Психолог: Вы сейчас в декрете?
Наталья: Я безработная. Ребенку скоро только 1.5 годика будет.
Психолог: Давайте поговорим о том, в чем вы раньше видели смысл и цель в своей жизни?
Наталья: В успехах в спорте и карьерном росте. Ни в первом, ни во втором мне не удалось добиться своей цели за 8 лет.
Психолог: Были ли эти цели реалистичными?
Наталья: Да, но везде было НО, которое не могло мне дать возможности добиться этого. В спорте — без толстого кошелька сложно продвинуться вперед. В работе — связей нужных нет.
Психолог: То, что вы достигли не всех целей или не в том объеме, в каком мечтали, вы переживаете как потерю?
Наталья: Да.

[ТЕКСТ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qLW1.png)

Comment: Вот эти перлы — независимо от стиля — никуда не годятся: _строила цель работать в конкретной компании; потом, проработав 8 лет в одной конторе, меня уволили._

Comment: Газетная публицистика, но не очень грамотная, корректора нужно привлечь к работе.

Answer (score 1):

[Стили русского литературного языка](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/790-51_obschaya_harakteristika_stilei_stilevoe_rassloenie_leksiki_emocionalno_ekspressivnaya_okraska_slova.html)

> В современном русском литературном языке выделяют обычно пять стилей:
>   •научный,
>   •официально-деловой (деловой),
>   •газетно-публицистический (публицистический),
>   •художественный,
>   •разговорный.

Видно, как говорится, невооруженным взглядом, что это не научный, не деловой и не художественный стиль. Остается выбрать между публицистическим и разговорным.

Хотя элементы разговорного стиля можно найти в речи Натальи, в целом преобладает публицистический стиль. Вот лишь некоторые его признаки:

-полные предложения с прямым порядком слов;
-газетные клише ("отсутствием смысла, цели в моей жизни", "стремилась добиться успехов в спорте", "добиться своей цели", "были ли эти цели реалистичными");
-тропы ("без толстого кошелька сложно продвинуться вперед").